# React-Native Promises and Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager, I am trying to connect to a custom bluetooth device and change values on it. However, steps have to go in a specific order and wait for the last step to finish before continuing. 
Part of what I currently have...

```
BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, keyCharacteristic, stringToBytes("device.id")).then(() => {
                          console.log('Wrote key');
                          BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, valueCharacteristic, deviceID).then(() => {
                            console.log('Saved Val');
                            BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, saveCharacteristic, saveVal).then(() => {
                              console.log('Save');
```

As you can see, it ends up being a giant nested function.

What I would want it to look like (psuedo code):

```
//update name
  await a.write //wait for completion
  await b.write //wait for completion
  await c.write //wait for completion
//NAME updated
//update description
  a.write //wait for completion
  b.write //wait for completion
  c.write //wait for completion
```

I believe I have to do something with promises and then statements, currently I have functions nested in functions but I know there is a better way to write it. I know how to do this in C, with await functions, but how can I do this in Javascript?

Any tips on the best way to write this? Or even an example of how to write a functioning promise that would work in this scenario would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, you can declare an async function and use the away statment. An another way is to implement a queue of command to write to the bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this:

```
const writeData = async () => {
    await BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, keyCharacteristic, stringToBytes("device.id"));
    await BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, valueCharacteristic, deviceID);
    await BleManager.write(peripheral.id, service, saveCharacteristic, saveVal);
    
    console.log("Wrote 3 characteristics!");

}
```

Note that the return type of `BleManager.write` is `void`, so there's no use in saying `const resp = write(`.